# Expire commitment tokens after extended period of time

Tags: feature-request, area-51, commitment-fulfillment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Commitment should fail after beta, user's commitment weight should reflect past failed commitments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92688/commitment-should-fail-after-beta-users-commitment-weight-should-reflect-past)

As per my previous question about the [Japanese.SE commitment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118430/how-can-i-fulfill-my-commitment-to-japanese-se-on-area-51/118452#118452) and others questions about [uncommitting to a site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60731/how-do-i-uncommit-to-a-stack-exchange) it would be nice if there was a way for the commitment to either expire or open up and allow the user to bow out after a given amount of time.

For example, a commitment could expire after the site has been active for an extended period of time (i.e. 180 days given that 90 is the time indicated on the commitment page) at which point the token would revert and perhaps after 90 days a user could withdraw their commitment with a reputation penalty if they are unable to meet the needs of the site.

Comment: @AdamDavis This is a little different. Your topic was about failing commitments after a beta ends, this one is about withdrawing commitments during a beta (with an appropriate penalty).  Now that betas can go on for a year or more, you can get stuck for a long time on a site that didn't turn out the way you expected.  Instead of posting 10 bad questions to escape with a fulfilled commitment bonus, it'd be nice to be able to withdraw your commitment manually and say "I screwed up and probably shouldn't have been in this beta" or "I lost interest and want out."

Comment: @RobZ So you're saying that the general answers will be different?  The specific solution we suggest is *slightly* different, but the basic problem is the same. If the community feels it's worthwhile to keep both questions around, though, then that's fine.

Comment: @RobZ How does the system tell the two apart?  There may be a difference in motivation, but the system can't tell if a person only posted 3 questions and 5 answers because they got tired of it, or because they are out of their league.  In either situation a user might want out of their commitment in order to commit to something else.

Comment: @RobZ So the questions are essentially the same then.

Comment: Questions about Area 51 should be asked on discuss.area51.stackexchange.com.